# spark streaming serialization error

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, spark-streaming, bigdata

I am running into serialization error in spark-streaming application. Below is my driver code:

```
package com.test
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.Serializable


object SparkFiller extends Serializable{
 def main(args: Array[String]): Unit ={
 val sparkConf = new 
SparkConf().setAppName("SparkFiller").setMaster("local[*]")
// println("test")
sparkConf.set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
sparkConf.registerKryoClasses(Array(classOf[firehoseToDocumentDB]))
sparkConf.registerKryoClasses(Array(classOf[PushToDocumentDB]))
var TimeStamp_Start = 1493836050
val TimeStamp_Final = 1493836056
var timeStamp_temp = TimeStamp_Start - 5;
// val send_timestamps = new firehoseToDocumentDB(TimeStamp_Start,TimeStamp_Final);
// send_timestamps.onStart();
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(5))
val lines = ssc.receiverStream(
new firehoseToDocumentDB(TimeStamp_Start.toString(),TimeStamp_Final.toString()))
// val timestamp_stream = ssc.receiverStream(new firehoseToDocumentDB(TimeStamp_Start.toString(),TimeStamp_Final.toString()))
lines.foreachRDD(rdd => {
  rdd.foreachPartition(part => {
    val dbsender = new PushToDocumentDB();
    part.foreach(msg =>{
      var jsonobject = new JSONObject(part)
      var temp_pitr = jsonobject.getString("pitr")
      println(temp_pitr)
      if ( TimeStamp_Final >= temp_pitr.toLong) {
        ssc.stop()
      }
      dbsender.PushFirehoseMessagesToDocumentDb(msg)
    })
    // dbsender.close()
  })
})

println("line",line)))
println("ankush")
ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
 }

}
```

When I add the below lines to the code

```
      var jsonobject = new JSONObject(part)
      var temp_pitr = jsonobject.getString("pitr")
      println(temp_pitr)
      if ( TimeStamp_Final >= temp_pitr.toLong) {
        ssc.stop()
      }
```

I get an error:

```
  Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:304)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:294)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:122)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2055)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(RDD.scala:919)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(RDD.scala:918)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.foreachPartition(RDD.scala:918)
at com.boeing.SparkFiller$$anonfun$main$1.apply(SparkFiller.scala:26)
at com.boeing.SparkFiller$$anonfun$main$1.apply(SparkFiller.scala:25)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:661)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:661)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:426)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:49)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:49)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:49)
at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:39)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobScheduler.scala:224)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:224)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:224)
at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:223)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
 Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext
 Serialization stack:
- object not serializable (class: 
org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext, value: 
org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext@780e1bb5)
- field (class: com.boeing.SparkFiller$$anonfun$main$1, name: ssc$1, type: 
class org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext)
- object (class com.boeing.SparkFiller$$anonfun$main$1, <function1>)
- field (class: com.boeing.SparkFiller$$anonfun$main$1$$anonfun$apply$1, 
name: $outer, type: class com.boeing.SparkFiller$$anonfun$main$1)
- object (class com.boeing.SparkFiller$$anonfun$main$1$$anonfun$apply$1, <function1>)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:47)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:101)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:301)
... 30 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

If I remove those lines of code it is working good.

The issue is because of using the ssc.stop() in the rdd. Is there any otherway that I can call a shutdown hook from the rdd if it satisfies the condition.

Comment: You cannot execute `ssc.stop()` while inside the `foreachRDD`, you should wait the completion.

Comment: Why don't add `ssc.stop()` after `ssc.awaitTermination()`?

Comment: @freedev the reason why I kept is I want to stop the spark execution if there is it satisfies the if condition.

Comment: @freedev is there a way that I can stop the streaming if it is in the if condition.
ssc.stop() is causing the issue.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Issue is because of using the ssc.stop() in the rdd.

You are right! Any of the Spark contexts are not serializable and cannot be used inside any of the tasks.

> is there any otherway that I can call a shutdown hook from the rdd if it satisfies the condition.

In order to control the lifecycle of your streaming application, you should consider overriding a listener and stop the context based on your condition. I have done enough research and found out that this the only feasible solution.

Please refer to my answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37556179/spark-streaming-how-not-to-restart-receiver-after-receivers-failure/41142701?s=2%7C5.0062#41142701) to understand how to stop the streaming application based on certain condition.